# Extract numbers from a character vector and adding leading zeros

Tags: r, regex

I have a character-vector with the following structure:

```
GDM3
PER.1.1.1_1
PER.1.10.2_1
PER.1.1.32_1
PER.1.1.4_1
PER.1.1.5_1
PER.11.29.1_1
PER.1.2.2_1
PER.31.2.3_1
PER.1.2.44_1
PER.5.2.25_1
```

I want to extract the three numbers in the middle of middle of that ID and add leading numbers if they are only single digits. The finale vector can be a character vector again. In the end the result should look like this:

```
GDM3
010101
011002
010132
010104
010105
112901
010202
310203
010244
050225
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
tmp <- strcapture("\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)_", X$GDM3, 
                  proto = list(a=0L, b=0L, c=0L)) |>
  lapply(sprintf, fmt = "%02i")
do.call(paste0, tmp)
#  [1] "010101" "011002" "010132" "010104" "010105" "112901" "010202" "310203" "010244" "050225"
```

Explanation:

- `strcapture` extracts the known patterns into a `data.frame`, with names and classes defined in `proto` (the actual values in `proto` are not used);
- `lapply(sprintf, fmt="%02i")` zero-pads to 2 digits all columns of the frame
- `do.call(paste, tmp)` concatenates each row of the frame into a single string.

---

Data

```r
X <- structure(list(GDM3 = c("PER.1.1.1_1", "PER.1.10.2_1", "PER.1.1.32_1", "PER.1.1.4_1", "PER.1.1.5_1", "PER.11.29.1_1", "PER.1.2.2_1", "PER.31.2.3_1", "PER.1.2.44_1", "PER.5.2.25_1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming GDM3 shown in the Note at the end, read it creating a data frame and the use sprintf to create the result.

```
with( read.table(text = GDM3, sep = ".", comment.char = "_"), 
  sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", V2, V3, V4) )
```

giving:

```
 [1] "010101" "011002" "010132" "010104" "010105" "112901" "010202" "310203"
 [9] "010244" "050225"
```

### Note

```
GDM3 <- c("PER.1.1.1_1", "PER.1.10.2_1", "PER.1.1.32_1", "PER.1.1.4_1", 
  "PER.1.1.5_1", "PER.11.29.1_1", "PER.1.2.2_1", "PER.31.2.3_1", 
  "PER.1.2.44_1", "PER.5.2.25_1")
```